# Iphone - is controller freed after push?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

is my UIViewController freed when i call another controller ?
How to release memory of controller when i push to another controller ? i take more than 40Mo and application leave because of LOW MEMORY(No leak).

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[MainListController alloc] init:self] animated:NO];

@interface MainListController : UIViewController
...
- (id)init: (id)ref;
```

when i call on init function the dealloc of controller i was :

```
[ref dealloc];
```

i've this error :

```
objc[70754]: FREED(id): message isEqual: sent to freed object=0xe216b0
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION”.
```

- (void)dealloc {[super dealloc];}

Comment: @Nicolas: This code you have posted above is absolutely leaking. The navigationController is retaining your controller and you are creating it without autoreleasing it there. You leak absolutely every time you push a controller this way. You must do something like: [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[[MainListController alloc] init:self] autorelease] animated:NO];

Comment: Also, make sure that your code in your view controller's init:self call doesn't retain the variable you passed it or you will have a retain cycle, and depending on how/where this nav controller is created, that may be leaking too.

Comment: i don't lose memory because i never come back to this controller, that's why i want to release it!do you have another solution ?

Comment: Yes: MainListController* mlc = [[MainListController alloc] init:self]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:mlc animated:NO]; [mlc release]; -- this is how it should be. The navigation controller will release it when it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't dealloc `UIViewControllers` that are not visible. What happens when the controllers on top pop off the navigation controller? What would the OS display then?

Instead you should implement the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method in all your controllers. These should `release` (not `dealloc`) as much *cached* data as possible. Anything that you can recalculate or bring back in from disk should be considered.

This is better than just `dealloc`ing views that are not visible as you really don't know how much memory is available in advance. On an iPhone 3GS you might have plenty of memory left even when using 40Mb.

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should. If you really want to release memory as you flip to MainListController, why not release the memory before you call the pushViewController method?

Comment: if i call [self release];
before 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[MainListController alloc] init:self] animated:NO];
it's working, are you sure, i will not BAD acces ? because i release self and after i do self.navigation... Thanks

Comment: No, you can't release the UIViewController while it's still in the navigation controller stack. You need to release cached data, not the controller itself.

Comment: i found in another ask to do self.view = nil; 
is view and all subview will be release on my controller ? thk lot!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot (and should not) release/dealloc a parent view controller when pushing a new one onto the navigation stack. You can unload the view by responding to the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` message.

There are several other problems with your code:

1. Never ever call `[obj dealloc]` manually. Always use `[obj release]`.
2. Your `init` method name should be more descriptive as to not conflict with the predefined `init` method. You should also (possibly) strongly type the `ref` argument if you need to use it. Something like `(id)initWithParent:(UIViewController*)ref` would be better.
3. Your code is leaking a `MainListController` object, since you are alloc/init'ing it and then handing it to navigationController. Change your code to `[[[MainListController alloc] initWithParent:self] autorelease]`.